# What exactly is wrong with this code...?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to find the largest value in an array with this...what am I doing wrong?

```
/*finds the largest value in an array*/
#include <stdio.h>
void find_large(int (*ar), int size, int *ptr1);
int main(void) {
    int array[10] = {1, 33, 4, 85, 132, -9, 0, 12, 99, 133};
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    int largest = 0;
    int *ptr1 = &largest;
    find_large(array, size, &ptr1);
    printf("The largest element is %d.\n", largest);
}

void find_large(int (*ar), int size, int *ptr1) {
    int count, largest = (*ar)[0];
    for(count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        if(*ar[count] > largest) {
            largest = (*ar)[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `&ptr1`? It's already an `int *`

Comment: I don't know how any of this works and can't find a clear source for learning about pointers in functions and how they relate to arrays.

Comment: `(*ar)[0];` , `*ar` is `aray[0]`:`int`. `largest = (*ar)[0];` --> `largest = ar[count];`

Comment: Read your compiler messages, you should get an error for passing `&ptr1` to the function, and also for doing `(*ar)[0]` ,and `*ar[count]`

Comment: [Here is the C FAQ on arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void find_large(int *ar, int size, int *ptr1);

int main(void) {
    int array[10] = {1, 33, 4, 85, 132, -9, 0, 12, 99, 133};
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    int largest = 0;
    //int *ptr1 = &largest;//Not required
    find_large(array, size, &largest);
    printf("The largest element is %d.\n", largest);
    return 0;
}

void find_large(int *ar, int size, int *ptr1) {
    int count, largest = ar[0];
    for(count = 1; count < size; count++) {
        if(ar[count] > largest) {
            largest = ar[count];
        }
    }
    *ptr1 = largest;
}
```

Comment: Now, if you are willing, can you explain step by step **as if I had an IQ of -10** how this works, and what was wrong with mine?

I notice a difference in notation being a primary thing. Why?

Comment: @dsadsadsa The main error of your : 1)You have to `(*ar)[index]` when it should be a `ar[index]`. 2)You are not using the pointer(`int *ptr1` at `find_large`) to return the value. 3)`int *ptr1 = &largest;` : You have assigned to a pointer to int from ponter to pointer to int.

Comment: But from what I understood, pointer notation == array notation.

And I don't understand what you mean by 3.

Comment: sorry 3) about for `&ptr1`(pass to `find_large`), is not `int *ptr1 = &largest;`.

Comment: So `ptr notation != array notation`

Comment: @dsadsadsa if `int *pointer` then `*pointer` type  is `int`. (`pointer[index]` == `array[index]` but `(*pointer:int)[index]` wrong.It does not mean they.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand a _little bit_ of the magic of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `ptr1` inside the function `find_large`, so the largest element is never returned.

Also note that you need to say `ptr1` instead of `&ptr1`.

Comment: I get these errors...can you help?

largest_array.c:14:28: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  int count, largest = (*ar)[0];
                            ^
largest_array.c:16:6: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   if(*ar[count] > largest) {
      ^
largest_array.c:17:19: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
    largest = (*ar)[0];

Comment: @dsadsadsa: You made extra changes to the code that I didn't tell you. What you ran is not the same as in your question.

Comment: All I did was remove the &ptr1

Comment: @dsadsadsa: That's not what I see in your comment though, I see a different change.

Comment: I didn't change anything else.

Comment: @dsadsadsa: You didn't change `largest = (ar)[0]`?

Comment: Didn't touch that part. **All I changed was the &ptr1**

Comment: @dsadsadsa: Then why does your question say `largest = (*ar)[0]` whereas your comment says `largest = (ar)[0]`?

Comment: @dsadsadsa: Ohh, I see what happened now -- it's because asterisks italicize text inside comments on Stack Overflow. You should be aware of that in the future; use backticks to separate code from non-code to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @dsadsadsa: As for your question: hmm, taking another look at it, `*ar[count]` looks wrong; are you sure it even compiled in the first place? It should be just `ar[count]`.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want pointer arguments as an array and pointer arguments as pointer i added the return value removing the word largest in your function():)

```
/*finds the largest value in an array*/
#include <stdio.h>

int find_large(int *ar, int size, int *ptr1);

int main(void) {

    int array[10] = {1, 33, 4, 85, 132, -9, 0, 12, 99, 133};
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    int largest = 0;
    largest = find_large(array, size, &largest);
    printf("The largest element is %d.\n", largest);
}

int find_large(int *ar, int size, int *ptr1) {
    int count; *ptr1 = ar[0];
    for(count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        if(ar[count] > *ptr1) {
           *ptr1 = ar[count];
        }
    }
    return *ptr1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let us use the pointer completely in your functions because the array without a bracket is the pointer of the first element of that array see your functions now all pointers :)

```
/*finds the largest value in an array*/
#include <stdio.h>

int find_large(int *ar, int size, int *ptr1);

int main(void) {

    int array[10] = {1, 33, 4, 85, 132, -9, 0, 12, 99, 133};
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    int largest = 0;
    largest = find_large(array, size, &largest);
    printf("The largest element is %d.\n", largest);
}

int find_large(int *ar, int size, int *ptr1) {
    int *p_array;
    int count; *ptr1 = *ar;
    for(count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        if(*ar> *ptr1) {
           *ptr1 = *ar;
        }
     *ar++;
    }
    return *ptr1;
}
```